# ThinkStats BiasPMF

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function

I have a question on an example in ThinkStats. The question is addressing bias of the distribution perceived by a runner in the race. The goal is to adjust the PMF function to represent the distribution as perceived by the runner. How to you recalculate the probabilities as perceived by the runner? I found the solution and my graph takes a similar form but is not as rigid, ie my probabilities are off. My probabilities seem to rise as the speed of the runner increases, which doesn't make intuitive sense. See Below...

[image]

Here is a link to the solution, doesn't clarify exactly how this is done. The question is at the bottom. https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2/blob/master/code/chap03soln.ipynb

Looking for the general process of how this would be done.

Thanks.

Full question below.

Exercise: In most foot races, everyone starts at the same time. If you are a fast runner, you usually pass a lot of people at the beginning of the race, but after a few miles everyone around you is going at the same speed. When I ran a long-distance (209 miles) relay race for the first time, I noticed an odd phenomenon: when I overtook another runner, I was usually much faster, and when another runner overtook me, he was usually much faster.

At first I thought that the distribution of speeds might be bimodal; that is, there were many slow runners and many fast runners, but few at my speed.

Then I realized that I was the victim of a bias similar to the effect of class size. The race was unusual in two ways: it used a staggered start, so teams started at different times; also, many teams included runners at different levels of ability.

As a result, runners were spread out along the course with little relationship between speed and location. When I joined the race, the runners near me were (pretty much) a random sample of the runners in the race.

So where does the bias come from? During my time on the course, the chance of overtaking a runner, or being overtaken, is proportional to the difference in our speeds. I am more likely to catch a slow runner, and more likely to be caught by a fast runner. But runners at the same speed are unlikely to see each other.

Write a function called ObservedPmf that takes a Pmf representing the actual distribution of runners’ speeds, and the speed of a running observer, and returns a new Pmf representing the distribution of runners’ speeds as seen by the observer.

Compute the distribution of speeds you would observe if you ran a relay race at 7 mph with this group of runners.

Comment: Your graphic, because it is not explained or labeled, is meaningless.  Since understanding the question depends on understanding the graphic, please provide edits to clarify your post.

Comment: @whuber Does it make sense what I am trying to do. The distribution of runners is normal. I am trying to represent a distribution as seen by some in the race running at a certain rate. So people running at a rate close to his pace should have a high probability of being passed or passing him.

Comment: At the moment this question is not very self-contained - I don't the question itself makes sense without reading the external link. At the least some explanation of "as perceived by" would help.

Comment: +1 I formulated this question some 27 years ago when I began driving home from work late at night.  It's possible to obtain information about the distribution of driving speeds on the highway simply by counting the number of passing cars, the number of cars you are passing, and knowing your own (roughly constant) speed.  Thinking about it can give you something to do while you drive... .